# How do you configure emmet to show hints with tags in backticks?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using a VS Code. I have a HTML file with section  and I tried to add function where I'm returning a HTML code in backticks. Emmet doesn't work I have to type all html tags myself. Hint is missing.

Comment: without an example it is hard to see what you want, you mean template strings?

Comment: type the HTML outside template string, cut-paste it inside template string, or select HTML and type back tick

Comment: Yes, I mean template strings.

Comment: you can select a space inside the template string, then execute command: **Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation` and then type your emmet string